# sklearn pipeline with transformed fitted with different set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm building a text classifier (13 categories) with sklearn and I'm trying to implement a pipeline in order to make a CV grid search for the classifier and vectorizer paramters (min_df, max_df, etc. ).

The classifier is going to be used in a set of already available 50k documents and I have for training around 5k annotated near similar documents.

Since the annotated training documents are not exactly from the same source I don't want to train the classifier using features extract from the annotated corpus but from the main not annotated corpus. Therefore, I first do a TfidfVectorizer fit in the main non annotated documents:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),min_df = 0.01,max_df = 0.95,stop_words = None,use_idf=True,smooth_idf = True)
vectorizer.fit(non_annotated_docs)
```

and then, from this learned vocabulary, I calculate the features that will be used as input to the classifier:

```
X_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(annotated_docs)
X_tfidf = X_tfidf.toarray()
```

So my question is how can I do the pipeline with gridsearchcsv for the annotated_docs corpus, but using the fit from non_annotated_docs?